# Twitter API, Searching with dollar signs

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, windows-10, anaconda

This code opens a twitter listener, and the search terms are in the variable, upgrades_str. Some searches work, and some don't. I added AMZN to the upgrades list just to be sure there's a frequently used term since this is using an open Twitter stream, and not searching existing tweets.

Below, I think we only need to review numbers 2 and 4.

I'm using Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

**Variable searches**

1. Searching with: upgrades_str: ['AMZN', 'SWK', 'AIQUY', 'SFUN', 'DOOR']  = returns tweets such as 'i'm tired of people'
2. Searching with: upgrades_str: ['$AMZN', '$SWK', '$AIQUY', '$SFUN', '$DOOR'] = returns tweets as as 'Chicago to south Florida. Hiphop lives'.   ***This search is the one I wish worked.***

**Explicit searches**

3. Searching by replacing the variable 'upgrades_str' with the explicit string: ['AMZN', 'SWK', 'AIQUY', 'SFUN', 'DOOR'] = returns 'After being walked in on twice, I have finally figured out how to lock the door here in Sweden'.  This one at least has the search term 'door'.
4. Searching by replacing the variable 'upgrades_str' with the explicit string: ['$AMZN', '$SWK', '$AIQUY', '$SFUN', '$DOOR'] = returns '$AMZN $WFM $KR $REG $KIM: Amazon’s Whole Foods buy puts shopping centers at risk as real'.  ***So the explicit call works, but not the identical variable.***
5. Explicitly searching for ['$AMZN'] = returns a good tweet: 'FANG setting up really good for next week! Added $googl jun23 970c avg at 4.36. $FB $AMZN'.
6. Explicitly searching for ['cool'] returns 'I can’t believe I got such a cool Pillow!'

   ```
   import tweepy
   import dataset
   from textblob import TextBlob
   from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError
   import json

   db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///tweets.db')

   class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

   def on_status(self, status):
       if status.retweeted:
           return

       description = status.user.description
       loc = status.user.location
       text = status.text
       coords = status.coordinates
       geo = status.geo
       name = status.user.screen_name
       user_created = status.user.created_at
       followers = status.user.followers_count
       id_str = status.id_str
       created = status.created_at
       retweets = status.retweet_count
       bg_color = status.user.profile_background_color
       blob = TextBlob(text)
       sent = blob.sentiment

       if geo is not None:
           geo = json.dumps(geo)

       if coords is not None:
           coords = json.dumps(coords)

       table = db['tweets']
       try:
           table.insert(dict(
               user_description=description,
               user_location=loc,
               coordinates=coords,
               text=text,
               geo=geo,
               user_name=name,
               user_created=user_created,
               user_followers=followers,
               id_str=id_str,
               created=created,
               retweet_count=retweets,
               user_bg_color=bg_color,
               polarity=sent.polarity,
               subjectivity=sent.subjectivity,
           ))
       except ProgrammingError as err:
           print(err)

   def on_error(self, status_code):
       if status_code == 420:
           return False

   access_token = 'token'
   access_token_secret = 'tokensecret'
   consumer_key = 'consumerkey'
   consumer_secret = 'consumersecret'

   auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
   auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
   api = tweepy.API(auth)

   stream_listener = StreamListener()
   stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
   stream.filter(track=upgrades_str, languages=['en'])
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer, in case someone has the problem in the future: "Note that punctuation is not considered to be part of a #hashtag or @mention, so a track term containing punctuation will not match either #hashtags or @mentions."  From: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track

And for multiple terms, the string, which was converted from a list, needs to be changed to ['term1,term2']. Just strip out the apostrophes and spaces:

```
upgrades_str = re.sub('[\' \[\]]', '', upgrades_str)
upgrades_str = '[\''+format(upgrades_str)+'\']'
```